# Switch socket server on disconnect

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to connect a new server when the first server is down and attempted in reconnect_failed. Upto now it is working fine, first server disconnects, second server connected and listening the message.

```
    socket.on('reconnect_failed', function () {
    console.log("reconnect_failed");
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000',{
            'reconnectionDelay': 100,
            'reconnect':false,
            'reconnectionAttempts': max_reconnects});
    console.log(socket);
});

socket.on('new message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = msg;
});
```

But at the client side "new message" event is not listened by second server. Due to that socket is initiated inside reconnect failed. Is there any other way to process with less code.

Comment: @xShirase , Please look at this question. Expected you can help on this. thanks in advance. will try to learn the usuage of the website.

Comment: No problems, this site is great so we all have to try our best to keep it that way. Let me see what I can do for your problem now that it is at the right place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have a function to switch server on disconnection. 
Something like :

```
function initSocket(i){
   sockets = io.connect(servers[i], {
            'reconnectionDelay': 100,
            'reconnect':false,
            'reconnectionAttempts': max_reconnects});
   sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
       socket.on('connect',function(data){});

       socket.on('new message', function(msg){
           console.log(msg);
           document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = msg;
       });

       socket.on('reconnect_failed', function () {
           console.log("reconnect_failed");
           i==0 ? 1 : 0; //switch the value of i
           initSocket(i) //init a socket on the other server
       });
   });
}

var servers = ["http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:4000"];

initSocket(0); //start with server 0 (http://localhost:3000)
```

This should give you the switch between your 2 servers on disconnect, with the exact same properties and event listeners. When one crashes, the other takes over.

Comment: I haven't tested that, I'm not on my pc. if there's a typo let me know, but I guess you see the point of the switch function

Comment: This is awesome, You have good logical mind. Thanks for your idea. Its is working... @xshirase